# Are the limits shown or set by ulimit per resource and per process?

Tags: bash, ulimit

Bash's `ulimit` concerns about limits on different kinds of resources.

Is it correct a limit shown or set by `ulimit` is per-resource?

Is each such limit the sum of the resources available to all the processes, 
instead of the limit of the resource available to each process?

Or are some limits per-resource, and some limits per-resource and per-process?  How can we tell which is which case?

Related http://forums.devshed.com/programming-42/whats-difference-sysconf-rlimit-955656.html
Thanks.

Comment: This ground has been trodden before, four years ago, at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117076/ .

Answer (score -1):

As you can read in the man page:

http://schillix.sourceforge.net/man/man2/getrlimit.2.html

or

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setrlimit.html

these limits are per process

Comment: In more comprehensive user manuals from other operating systems one can read that _only some_ of them are per process.  (-:

Comment: The official limits are per process. I mentioned Solaris and POSIX ad this is from the inventor (BSD) and from the standard. If there is a specific operating system that added nonstandard resources, this may be different, but it seems that you don't know such a limit either.

Comment: @schily “The maximum number of processes available to a single user” is obviously not per-process.

Comment: This is a Linux extension and was neither in the BSD original implementation, nor is it in the POSIX standard.

Comment: `RLIMIT_NPROC` (which isn't even the only one that is not per-process) has been in the BSDs for approaching a quarter of a century at this point, starting with 4.4BSD.  It's definitely time to catch up with those manual pages that I mentioned.  (-: